# loading html file into html with jquery for offline/local project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offline

I'm trying to load an html file into another html file for an app-project. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
$.get('mod_navigation.html', function(data) { $('body').append(data);});
```

works as it should and is all I need :-) ... yet it does only work when i upload it on my server and test it via browser from there. Doing it via browser offline, so with the local files, the html file does not get included. Since the app later should work "offline" this does get me worried. How can I get this code to work offline/local?

Thanks in advance,
ANB_Seth

Comment: Are your libs path correct? If you use `windows` on local and `linux` at server its possible the libs path to be wrong.

Comment: well the "mod_navigation.html" is in the same directory as the "index.html" its loaded into ... not sure what libs path you are refering to?

Comment: I mean `path/to/jquery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use load()?

Load can work in localhost:

```
 $('body').append($('<div id="nav">').load('mod_navigation.html'));
```

This appends a div to the body with the content (which is more common).

To replace the body entirely, just use:

```
 $("body").load('mod_navigation.html');
```

Just remember that load paths from the root directory, not from the parent page's directory.

In localhost, there are restrictions. You will get a Access to restricted URI denied from a Get.

You could try JsonP or you could use HTML5 web app file storage.

Comment: okay thank you, I will try to work with load :-) ... one more question thou ... is there a way to "append" the entire "mod_navigation.html" into the body, not just create a div, append that and load it in there?